# How can you teleport behind a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an item for an "assassin" class, where when you hold it, you teleport behind the nearest player. I have found another question, but it only applies to armor stands and doesn't apply to players. So how can you get it to teleport behind the nearest player, preferably looking towards that @p player.

Comment: /exectye command will help you

Answer (score 5):

The other answer is almost correct. Let `@s` be the assassin; we can run this comand:

```
execute
  as @p[distance=0.1..]
  at @s
run tp @p ^ ^ ^-1 facing entity @s
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
execute as @e[type=player,sort=nearest] run tp @p ^ ^ ^-1
```

Important: use `^`, not `~` to teleport, so you teleport one block behind the nearest players facing direction. Unfortuenetly I don't know how to look towards that @p player. nevertheless, I hope  the command will help you : )

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. Running this command causes me to teleport myself one block backwards, not relative to the nearest player. Please make sure you've tested your commands before attempting.